# Trying to avoid comma at end and add space after comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to write RegExp for validation

1. string will be alphanumeric with not having space between words.
2. after each word comma will be added by user and after that space get added
3. not allow space and comma in end of word and not allow more than 5 comma separated values

I wrote following regExp code but it fails on second.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(\, [0-9a-zA-Z]+){0,4}$
```

Comment: Do you mean `^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:, ?[0-9a-zA-Z]+){0,4}$`? That the space is optional? Note [`[A-z]` matches more than just ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926). It would help if you show your code.

Comment: Can you add the example that failed?

Comment: its get failed on e.g : 1, 2, 3,
which ends on comma 
if added space it shows the error regexp not match

Comment: Given `1, 2, 3, `, should it fail or not? What about `1, 2, 3,`? Same for `1, 2, 3, 4, 5,` variations

Comment: it get failed on `1, 2, 3,` on `1, 2, 3, ` working

Comment: You also need to change `A-z` to `A-Z`

Comment: Do you want a regex for live validation? Like `^[0-9a-zA-Z]*(?:(?:,(?: [0-9a-zA-Z]*)?)?){0,4}$`

Comment: You can also replace `[0-9a-zA-Z]` with `[^\W_]` to make it shorter if you wish

Comment: The current and accepted regexps are the same, so there was no issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:, [0-9a-zA-Z]+){0,4}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/vYdOoL/1